# socketio array.splice dont work if make console.log

Tags: socket.io, console.log, array-splice

Strange phenomenon. socketio

SERVER

i have that code...

```
socket.on('disconnect', function(){

    console.log('user disconnected');

    for(var i=0; i<stores.length; i++ ){

        var c = stores[i];

        if(c.socketid == socket.id){

            stores.splice(i,1);
            break;
        }
    }

});
```

everything goes well with the .splice. If i print the **stores** array from elsewhere, it displayed correct ...but in this situation

```
    socket.on('disconnect', function(){

            console.log('user disconnected');

            for(var i=0; i<stores.length; i++ ){

                var c = stores[i];

                if(c.socketid == socket.id){

                     for(var i=0; i<stores.length;i++){

                        console.log(i+" one"+stores[i].name+"-"+stores[i].id)

                     }

                    stores.splice(i,1);

                     for(var i=0; i<stores.length;i++){

                        console.log(i+" two"+stores[i].name+"-"+stores[i].id)

                     }

                    break;
                }
            }
    });
```

the array has not lost its values, i visit the page from my browser(i connected),

```
socket.on('storelogged', function (msg){

        var storeInfo = new Object();
        storeInfo.name      = msg.name;
        storeInfo.id         = msg.id;
        storeInfo.socketid     = socket.id;
        stores.push(storeInfo);

        console.log(msg.name + " has connected with " + msg.id + " id." );

});
```

so, **stores** pushed. But when i disconnected in the second situation of socket.on('disconnect',callback) the **stores** array still contains the values( in other words, splice dont work )

comment for giving, much and better information. Also you can test it and see the results

Comment: Your embedded `for` loops are overwriting the `i` variable from the top level `for` loop.  Either use `let` instead of `var` as in `for (let i = 0; ....)` for all your `for` loops or use a different variable name for the embedded `for` loops.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your embedded `for` loops are overwriting the `i` variable from the top level `for` loop.

Either use `let` instead of `var` as in `for (let i = 0; ....)` for all your `for` loops so each has a different locally scoped value of `i` and the inner loops won't overwrite the outer loops or use a different variable name for the embedded `for` loops or use `.forEach()` which creates a new variable for the index.

In addition, after you call `.splice()` on the array you are iterating, you have decrement the current array index from your `for` loop or you will skip looking at one of the values in the array because the `.splice()` moved it down into the index spot that you just removed and that your `for` loop has already iterated.

For example, you can change variable names of the inner `for` loops like this:

```
socket.on('disconnect', function () {
    console.log('user disconnected');
    for (var i = 0; i < stores.length; i++) {
        var c = stores[i];

        if (c.socketid == socket.id) {
            for (var j = 0; j < stores.length; j++) {
                console.log(j + " one" + stores[j].name + "-" + stores[j].id)
            }
            stores.splice(i, 1);
            // make sure not to skip the value we just moved into the i slot in the array
            i--;    
            for (var k = 0; i < stores.length; k++) {
                console.log(k + " two" + stores[k].name + "-" + stores[k].id)
            }
            break;
        }
    }
});
```

Or, you can use `let` for the `for` loops:

```
socket.on('disconnect', function () {
    console.log('user disconnected');
    for (var i = 0; i < stores.length; i++) {
        var c = stores[i];

        if (c.socketid == socket.id) {
            for (let i = 0; i < stores.length; i++) {
                console.log(i + " one" + stores[i].name + "-" + stores[i].id)
            }
            stores.splice(i, 1);
            // make sure not to skip the value we just moved into the i slot in the array
            i--;
            for (let i = 0; i < stores.length; i++) {
                console.log(i + " two" + stores[i].name + "-" + stores[i].id)
            }
            break;
        }
    }
});
```

Or, you can use `.forEach()`:

```
socket.on('disconnect', function () {
    console.log('user disconnected');
    for (var i = 0; i < stores.length; i++) {
        var c = stores[i];

        if (c.socketid == socket.id) {
            stores.forEach(function(item, index) {
                console.log(index + " one" + item.name + "-" + item.id)
            });
            stores.splice(i, 1);
            // make sure not to skip the value we just moved into the i slot in the array
            i--;
            stores.forEach(function(item, index) {
                console.log(index + " one" + item.name + "-" + item.id)
            });
            break;
        }
    }
});
```